# CloudFare error 1020 Access Denied in C# .net core

Tags: c#, rest, http

Hi I am trying to access an image hosting website's Api, I am able to upload files to it but if I try to retrieve the file suing the Api then an error "**CloudFare error 1020 Access Denied** " kind of is shown to me if I try to access it using any Tool like **Postman** or **RestClient** in C#, but when I retrieve the file using the download button on the website then I am not shown any error and Image is downloaded properly.

Here is my **RestClient** Code:-

```
var client = new RestClient("https://anonymousfiles.io/f/camps_5.jpg");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

JObject json = JObject.Parse(response.Content.ToString());
```

Comment: After a brief look at [the documenation](https://anonymousfiles.io/api.html), it appears that you need to pass the file `id`, not the `name`, as part of the url. Have you tried that? Also, it only mentions retrieving details about the file, not the file itself.

Comment: @RufusL Actually the things is this would return the information about the file uploaded but I am considering that I already have the file details like its name etc. and now I want to download it directly

Comment: I tried to copy the download link of the Download Button and tried to paste it in the browser to see if I can access the image but I cant, and in the same case if I just press the download button then I can see that image in a separate webpage(after downloaded), the point is why the click on that button is necessary to access that Url?

Comment: It appears that they don't support downloading the file itself - at least it's not documented anywhere. Even their api is called "File **Upload** API".

Comment: That maybe right that they won't allow to download file but why this happens that clicking on Download File Button would start file download but if I just Copy the link address of the download button and then try to paste it in separate tab then it wont download the file, Do they only allow to download file through pressing that Download button only!?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using curl and cloudFare. Add a user agent header with "Chrome/79" and there is a good chance that you will not get **CloudFare error 1020 Access Denied**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).